# Apply transitions on :hover not :active

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm not sure if it's possible, but here is what I did:

```
a {
    background-color: white;
    transition: all 1s;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: grey;
}

a:active {
    background-color: black;
}
```

But I would like the transitions not to apply on the :active (just on the :hover), I tried this:

```
a {
    background-color: white;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: grey;
    transition: all 1s;
}

a:active {
    background-color: black;
}
```

And the result is exactly the same (except that the effect is not reversed). Is it possible to do it in full CSS.

Thanks!

Comment: I can only think of applying the transition to `a:not(:active)`, but then what should happen when the element transitions from `:active` to `:hover` after you release the mouse while still hovering the element?

Comment: Yes, that's the solution. After the `:active` it simply goes back to the `:hover` state (immediately). But that's what we want with the `:active`, just to see the click event. Thanks

Comment: The problem is that it animates back to `:hover` instead of changing immediately, because the transition is defined for `:hover` (remember that we're talking about states, not events, in CSS). If that doesn't matter to you though, then I will post an answer.

Comment: Actually I don't really care about the transition (immediate or not) from `:active` to `:hover`. But I must admit that having a transition effect is pretty nice, so @kougiland 's solution fits perfectly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a {
    background-color: white;
    transition: all 1s;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: grey;
}

a:active {
    background-color: black;
    transition: none;
}
```

markup:

```
<menu type=list>
    <li><a>home</a></li>
    <li><a>work</a></li>
    <li><a>contact</a></li>
    <li><a>about</a></li>
</menu>
```

demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/7nwLF/

Comment: Those `!important`s aren't needed.

Comment: true but it s just for security reasons

Comment: Well, that was pretty simple. Thank you very much! That allows the transition from `:active` to `:hover`states, which makes a nice effect!